# Created a VM image, now need to deploy them over network

Tags: windows, networking, boot, virtual-machine, vmware

I've created a freshly installed version of Windows 8.1 "not yet activated" with all necessary software packages on VMWare Workstation. This image is considered the baseline for any computer within the company. Then, the image will be added to the domain controller.

The question is, how can I deploy this "virtual" image "physically" to replace the existing C: partition for all (or selected) network computers in which it must be bootable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have windows server 2008 or higher, use Windows Deployment Services to create a capture image. Boot your VM into that capture image and save it in a networked folder on your server. Then create a install image using your newly saved image back in WDS. Lastly, deploy your install image to all PCs. Best way to do this is via a PXE boot. Honestly, your going to want to do a bit of reading or YouTube watching as there are a lot of steps.

You also should look at getting MDT (Microsoft deployment toolkit) to help automate some of the deployment tasks. This will make the install lite touch, meaning that you still I will have to click at least once on each PC to image them. To make it 100% automated and click free, you'd need to purchase something like SCCM which is not cheap but given a big enough enterprise environment, could be beneficial.